# How can I keep excel from automatically changing the text color

Tags: microsoft-excel, automation, colors

I have a spreadsheet I use to check files off from. I change the text color to red if the file is incomplete, and highlight with yellow once finished. If I haven't seen the file yet, the cell remains unfilled with black text. However, recently when I open the file or change tabs and then go back, ALL of the cells have red text. Hitting Ctrl+Z typically works to get it close to what it had been before, but other cells will turn back to black that had been red and/or highlighted. Any suggestions to prevent this from happening would be great.

Comment: Are you using any conditional formatting? Other than Ctrl+z, what else have you tried?

Comment: I'm not using any conditional formatting. And I haven't tried anything else besides ctrl+z, and that's only to fix it after the issue has occurred, it has not prevented it from happening.

Comment: The data is in a table though, so I'm not sure if that's effecting it in anyway.

Comment: Does is all of your text red every time you open the file, or only when switching between sheets/tabs? Also, which version of Excel are you using?

Comment: I'm using Excel 2016. And it's only one column of text (the column that I am changing the colors in), that all turns to red text. And it almost always happens when opening the file, and then every so often it happens when I change sheets/tabs, or when I add a filter and then remove it, it will also happen every once in while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try File>Options>Advanced> and uncheck "Extend data range formats and formulas". Save/Close, then reopen and see if the problem persists.

NOTE: This will prevent certain formulas from updating if you extend the range of affected cells. For example, If you have in cell A2 `=SUM(A1:B1)` and you add data to cell C1, with Extend data range formats and formulas checked your sum formula will automatically update to `=SUM(A1:C1)`. This will not happen if you uncheck the box.

This will not affect any formulas you have "auto filling" in a table however.